# which ip address of my server should I use to connect my client to my server?

Tags: java, sockets, ip

IP address hidden for security.

---

I tried to connect two systems which are on different networks. I used public IP address but it is not working. Which IP address should I use in client code?

my public ip address: `103.**.***.127`.
This code worked when I connected both the systems to same wifi network.

client.java:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
class client implements ActionListener{
  JFrame f;
  Socket s;
  JButton B;
  String msg,temp;
  InetAddress inet1;
  InetSocketAddress inet;
  client() throws IOException,UnknownHostException{
    f=new JFrame ("Client");
    B=new JButton("Connect");
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(400,400);
    f.setLayout(null);
    B.setBounds(150,150,100,40);
    B.addActionListener(this);
    f.add(B);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(f.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    s=new Socket();
    inet1=InetAddress.getByName("103.**.***.127");
    inet=new InetSocketAddress(inet1,4321);
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      if(e.getSource()==B){
          try {
        s.connect(inet);
        System.out.println("connected");
          }
          catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
    client c=new client();
  }
}
```

server.java:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

class server implements ActionListener{
  JFrame f;
  ServerSocket ss;
  Socket s;
  JButton B;
  String msg,temp;
  JLabel j;
  server() throws IOException{
      ss=new ServerSocket(4321,1);
      s=ss.accept();
      f=new JFrame ("SERVER");
      B=new JButton("Click");
      j=new JLabel();
      f.setVisible(true);
      f.setSize(400,400);
      f.setLayout(null);
      B.setBounds(150,150,100,50);
      j.setBounds(100,100,200,50);
      B.addActionListener(this);
      f.add(B);f.add(j);
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(f.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      if(e.getSource()==B) {
          try {
        j.setText("connected to "+s.getInetAddress());
          }
          catch(Exception ex) {
              System.out.println(ex);
          }
      }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
    server p=new server();
  }
}
```

I got an exception
"java.net.connectionexception: connection timedout:....

Comment: The connection timeout just means the server takes too long to respond. You can customize the timeout on your request

Comment: When the client is not on the same network as the server, the client needs to connect to the server's public router IP, and the router needs to have port forwarding enabled to forward incoming packets to the server machine. Sounds like maybe you are missing that forwarding configuration.